# Excel application crashing on ThisWorkbook.Save - where ThisWorkbook is an add-in

Tags: vba

I have built an add-in that, apart for the code, is storing on its sheets some data that are functional to the add-in itself.

The user, through an user interface, can decide to remove some of the sheets from the add-in workbook, by selecting their names from a `ListBox` object appearing on the user form that shows up when called on the workbook currently in use. So the idea is:

```
For j = 0 To MyListBox.ListCount - 1
    If MyListBox.Selected(j) Then
        sheetsToDelete.Add ws(j) 'where ws(j) is the sheet with that name
    End If
Next j
```

The code above is not the real code, but just a sample to better express the concept. The real code works fine, I've tested in debug, but I just wanted to communicate the concept.

Once this is done, I would like to save the changes (i.e. the add-in after the sheets deletion) and so far I've done it with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

However, when this line of code is hit, "Excel application does not respond, the program will be terminated" (Excel workbook completely freezed):

[image]

I have checked in debug if the workbook is not corrupted, but it looks fine:

[image]

... it's my add-in...

[image]

... and it's containing the 2 sheets I expect it to contain:

[image]

Any tip on how to debug this? Unfortunately I cannot provide a full-reproduceable code snippet, I'm not being able..., but I might give more info if needed... anyone has encountered my some problem or can give me a nice tip?

Comment: It seems like modifying the contents of the Add-in file may not be the best approach. One workaround might be to set the `.Visible` property of those sheets to `xlVeryHidden` instead of deleting them outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IsAddin Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838249%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

There was another case where this was an issue.  Not sure how this affects the `.Save`:

```
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = False
'Run Code Here
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
```

Comment: @MatteoNNZ If you don't want them to see it can't you just turn off ScreenUpdating?

Comment: You changed the taste of my morning coffee. Thanks a lot, have a nice day!